# VI (VIM): delete/change right to left?

Tags: vim, vi

I often use "c-t-$char" change-till-character and "d-t-$char" and would love to be able to do the same thing in reverse.

An example:

```
cobbler reposync --only=puppetlabs-6Server-x86_64
```

If my cursor is at the end of the line and I want to delete backwards to the = char. What brought this on is my wanting to move from BASH emacs mode to vi mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `T` and `F` for that. For example `cT=` or `dF=` etc.

Answer (score 3):

`d-T-$char` deletes from the cursor position backwards without deleting `$char`,
`d-F-$char` with deleting `$char`