# Vi/vim - delete from end line including final character

Tags: vim, vi

I want to do something similar to this question [VI (VIM): delete/change right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9154212/301527) i.e. delete from the end of a line to the last instance of = in that line, which can be done using  `dT=` with the cursor placed at the end of the line.

However this and other such commands do not delete the final character of the line, so I have to add an `x` to that command. I don't mind doing this, yet it seems surprising that vim wouldn't have a command to delete from the current character. Is there one that I just haven't been able to find?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if your cursor is at the end of the line, you could try

```
F=D
```

oh, didn't notice that OP wants to keep the '='. then:

```
T=D
```

Comment: @BenjaminGolder yep, thanks for pointing out, didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can:

```
set virtualedit=onemore
```

This will let you move the cursor one characer beyond the end of the line. From that position, `dT=` will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `T=d$`? would that work?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to `:set virtualedit=onemore`, such that you can do: `$dT=`.

Reference at `:help 've'`.

Comment: Actually I think you need `$l` to move to the end of line plus one character.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more convoluted, but more powerful - I'm not sure if you intend to do one line at a time, or lots... use regular expression replace.

```
single line:
^               # go to beginning of line
:s/=[^=]*$/=/   # remove everything after =

whole file:
:%s/=[^=]*$/=/gc   # replace every instance in file, with prompts. remove c for no prompt.
```