# How to delete, including the current character?

Tags: vim

Let's say I've typed "abcdefg", with the cursor at the end. I want to delete back to the c, so that I only have "abc" left.

Is there a command like `d` that includes the current character? I know I could do `dTcx`, but the `x` feels like a work-around and I suppose there's a better solution.

Comment: I do this with the silliest way possible ever :D

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy `xxxx`? Or `ddOabc`?

Comment: Humm :D and sometimes using Del from `c`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vi/vim - delete from end line including final character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518324/vi-vim-delete-from-end-line-including-final-character)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Backward motions always start on the left of the current character for `c`, `y` and `d` which is somehow logical but also unnerving.

The only "clean" solutions I could think of either imply moving to the char after `c` first and then do a forward delete:

```
Tcde
```

or using visual mode:

```
vTcd
v3hd
```

But, given your sample and assuming you are entering normal mode just for that correction, the whole thing sounds extremely wasteful to me.

What about staying in insert mode and simply doing <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>?

Comment: +1 for the 4x`backspace`, I think I would do that way in real work.

Comment: Thanks. Of course this was just an example; there might be 12 or 30 characters to delete, and it might be in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
TcD
```

this will leave `abc` for your example... well if the `abcdefg` is the last word of the line.

if it is not the last word in that line, you may do:

```
ldTc
```

or golfing, do it within 3 key-stroke:

```
3Xx or l4X
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518819/353612) to a similar question : there is a setting to be allowed to go beyond the end of the line

From the doc :

> Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is
>       no actual character.  This can be halfway into a tab or beyond the end
>       of the line.  Useful for selecting a rectangle in Visual mode and
>       editing a table.
>       "onemore" is not the same, it will only allow moving the cursor just
>       after the last character of the line.  This makes some commands more
>       consistent.  Previously the cursor was always past the end of the line
>       if the line was empty.  But it is far from Vi compatible.  It may also
>       break some plugins or Vim scripts.  For example because |l| can move
>       the cursor after the last character.  Use with care!
>       Using the `$` command will move to the last character in the line, not
>       past it.  This may actually move the cursor to the left!
>       The `g$` command will move to the end of the screen line.
>       It doesn't make sense to combine "all" with "onemore", but you will
>       not get a warning for it.

In short, you could try `:set virtualedit=onemore`, and see if your environment is stable or not with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `d?c`
That will start `d` mode, search back to 'c' and then delete up to your cursor position.

Edit: nope, that does not include current position...

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your request, but does `3hd$` do it?

Comment: Yes, it does. Or `Fdd$`. But I'd like to work when I'm not at the end of the line too, and this also feels like a work-around. Basically, I'm asking if there is a motion/delete that includes the current character.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `vFdd` in this example. I think it's nicer than the other solutions since the command explicitly shows what to delete. It includes the current character and the specified character when deleting.

- `v`: enter visual mode (mark text)
- `F`: find/goto character backwards
- `d`: the character "d" that will be included for removal.
- `d`: delete command

Since it is visual mode, the cursor can also be moved before executing the actual removal `d`. This makes the command powerful even for deleting up to a non unique character by first marking a special character close to the character and then adjusting the position.