# vim delete find back including selected character

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following line

```
&.btn, &.btn-success
```

and the cursor is on the last s.

If I do `dF,`  it will delete backward the way I want it but will keep the `s`.

I want to be able to be on the s, and delete backwards, including the comma and including the last s.

Is there a way without extra keystrokes?

Comment: Is it really so hard to type `dF,x`?

Comment: Nop but I'm new to vim and don't want to teach myself bad habits =)

Comment: `dF,x` is not "elegant" but it's definitly not a bad habit. If it takes you 10 seconds to come up with `F,D` and only 1 to do `dF,x` then by all means do the latter.

Comment: True, haha.. But I always tend to think long term.. It'll take me 10 minutes to get a response now and 10 seconds to remember it next time but after a few times, I'll be using this and other keys better :-)

Comment: @Abdo It depends on a file type you editing. Your code similar to CSS. So deleting to the end of line will push you to write `{` symbol again, just in case :)

Comment: @hawk I'm using SASS so no curlies :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete, including the current character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804179/how-to-delete-including-the-current-character)

Comment: Nop, this is different as there's a backward find involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move to the comma first, then delete to the EOL:

```
F,D
```

Comment: I see! My problem was that I was doing d$ to delete to EOL although the cheat sheet in front of me clearly shows D is the way to go :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it in `VISUAL` mode. `vF,d`

Comment: Not a bad idea, +1... I chose @romainl 's answer because after trying both, his solution feels more natural to me although yours might feel better for someone else :-)

Comment: Note, this only works if your 'selection' option is set to "inclusive". On Windows, by default, that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
dvF,
```

`v` toggles the "inclusiveness" or "exclusiveness" of a motion.
See `:help inclusive` for more details

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/24wbuz/command_to_delete_one_full_word_backwards/

Comment: I like this alternative because the comma comes last, so it lends itself well to a simple mapping (in my case, to delete back to a certain character from insert mode).